# Runtime error when trying to access the members of a cell that has been registered

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a CollectionView cell that has an image view and a label within it. When I try to set either the image or the text within the label my program crashes within this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The cell is a custom class that has inherited from UICollectionViewCell, and the outlets have been created and linked in the storyboard:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I am setting the imageView with:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ss")
        return cell
    }
```

I originally thought there was something wrong with the image file location so I commented it out and tried to change the text of the label with:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        cell.textLabel.text = "Hello"
        return cell
    }
```

But that also caused a crash. What could cause a custom cell to load correctly but not have access to any of its' members?

EDIT: In the viewdidload function I registered my class like this:

```
self.collectionView?.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Are you connected the outlets ?

Comment: Yeah, I connected each of them in the storyboard

Comment: Is cell nil ? Did you check that ?

Comment: cell is not nil but when i make a breakpoint just before "return cell" I can see that the image view and text label are both nil. Is there another step to connect the outlets with the cell other than ctrl-drag?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the above mentioned case ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Edited to include the picture

Comment: I suspect that you are getting a normal UICollectionViewCell instead of your CustomCell

Comment: @MidhunMP But doesn't it say that it is of the type "ExerciseCell" in the debugger? (ExerciseCell is what I changed it to from 'CustomCell')

Comment: You are casting that right ? Don't cast it and try to use default property and check whether it's working

Comment: If I don't cast it I won't have access to the image view though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't register the class if the cell was made in a storyboard. Delete that line. Make sure you set the identifier for the cell in the storyboard. You only register the class if you're making the cell entirely in code.